# include once inside echo

Tags: php, string, include, echo

I have two headers which I'd like to display according to account type; "a" for admin type and "b" for regular user type.
I already have the enum set 'a','b'. Now, for the php after connecting to the database, I have:

```
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $name = $row["name"];
        $accounttype = $row["accounttype"];
          if($accounttype == "a"){
            $header = include_once "header_a.php";
          }
          if($accounttype == "b"){
            $header = include_once "header_b.php";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

As for the html, I have:

```
   <html>
   <body>

     <?php echo $accounttype; ?>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Edit:
Ok, I got it working the right way:

```
   <?php
    $header ="";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $name = $row["name"];
        $accounttype = $row["accounttype"];
          if($accounttype == "a"){
            include_once "header_a.php";
          }else{
          include_once "header_b.php";
       }
    }
    ?>

   <html>
   <body>

     <?php echo $header; ?>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I display a different headers according account type, one for admin and the other one for regular user? See, I'd like for the admin to have extra links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not something like this:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $name = $row["name"];
    $accounttype = $row["accounttype"];
}

include_once "header_".$accounttype.".php";
?>


<html>
<body>

    <?php echo $accounttype; ?>

</body>
</html>
```